# iOS Split View - Load XIB

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad

I am new to making iOS apps. I want to make a Split View app so I can have topics on the left and the content on the right.

I want to be able to pull the xib file and display it on the right. How can I do this?

I have a basic one working where it changes image, but not views. I want to display the xib file relating to the selected one in the array. Any tutorial to show me how to do this would be great.

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ECqCE4McWrs&feature=channel_video_title) is the video I watched.

P.S I am new to this app development. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. A split view controller manages two view controllers.
2. When you create a view controller, you can specify the .xib file from which it should load its view.
3. It follows, then, that when the user taps on a topic, your code can create a corresponding view controller (see UIViewController's `-initWithNibName:bundle:` method) and set that view controller as the split view controller's detail view controller.
4. It's possible to have an existing view controller load a new view from a .xib using NSBundle's `-loadNibNamed:bundle:owner:` method, but that's usually more work with no real advantage over replacing the entire view controller.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember, you should have access from your viewController to the property splitViewController, on which you can change the property  "viewControllers" to any array containing the rootViewController at index 0 and the detailViewController (set to your new detailViewController) at index 1.

If you don't want to have sveral controller for your views, I remember having used NSBundle methods to load a nib file and assign it to a controller. I believe this is another possibility but you have to test it.